# Find delimiter and print second array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, split

I have a data like this:

```
A=5 B=8 . C=8
A=4 . . C=4
A=8 . . C=3
```

I need to check all column in my file and if I find `letter=number` (for example A=5) I need print only `number`. And if there is missing value (`.`) just skip it.

So output should be:

```
5 8 . 8
4 . . 4
8 . . 3
```

I would use awk:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{split($0,arr2,"="); print arr2[2]}' infile.txt
```

Comment: No it is not fixed. Number of column is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk you could do this:

```
$ awk -F= -vRS='[ \t\n]+' '{printf "%s%s", (NF>1?$NF:$0), RT}' file
5 8 . 8
4 . . 4
8 . . 3
```

Awk seperates it's input into records, and the records into fields. With `-vRS='[ \t\n]+'` we set the record separator to a sequence of spaces, tabs or newlines. We also set the field seperator with `-F=` to the equal sign. So essentially we spit the input into records, with each record being a single word, and then we slit the records into fields using the `=` as a seperator.

With this part `'{printf "%s%s", (NF>1?$NF:$0), RT}'` we print the desired output. For each record, we can have two cases: If the number of fields (variable `NF`) is greater than one, that means that we have an equals, so we keep the last field of the record with `$NF`. If the record has a single field (no equals) we keep the field as is. We print first the desired value, and then the seperator that was matched when splitting the fields, which is stored in the `RT` variable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply it looks this is working perfectly fine. But i need to copy/paste name of my infile.xls - when I press TAB, it does not show my files. Where could be a problem? AWK version?

Comment: @Paul: The awk version shouldn't have anything to do with the tab-completion, that feature comes from bash I think.

Comment: but still your script works perfectly fine. Would be possible to comment parts? What is vRS? RT? :))

Comment: @Paul `RS` stands for the Record Seperator, which is a regular expression that specifies how the records are split. `RT` is the value of the Record Seperator for the specific record. I added a couple of paragraphs to explain how this works. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 4):

This awk one-liner works with gawk:

```
awk -F'\\S*=' -v OFS="" '{$1=$1}7' file
5 8 . 8
4 . . 4
8 . . 3
```

The idea is: remove `FOO=` by setting `FS`

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way to do this is with sed:

```
sed -e 's/[A-Z]\+=//g' infile.txt
```

This simply deletes all instances of a (bunch of) letter(s) followed by an equals sign.

Comment: Worth noting that `\+` is non-standard, so you need `-E` and `+` on some versions (or just use `*` since it works too).

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to interate over the fields and stripping off the portion upto `=` from start if the field starts with a letter, then `=`, and then any number at the end:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/^[A-Za-z]=[0-9]+$/) sub("^.*=", "", $i)}{print}'
```

If your a word of letters instead of a single one:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/^[A-Za-z]+=[0-9]+$/) sub("^.*=", "", $i)}{print}'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
A=5 B=8 . C=8
A=4 . . C=4
A=8 . . C=3

$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~/^[A-Za-z]=[0-9]+$/) sub("^.*=", "", $i)} { print }' file.txt  
5 8 . 8
4 . . 4
8 . . 3
```

Comment: thank you for reply. When I testing your solution on huge data, it does not work. Actually in real set of data is not A,B,C...etc but there are real word like - IMPACT=151, ENSP=544, PHENO=512...etc..

Comment: Still have file with no modification after run your script :-(. File is tab delimited. any idea?

Comment: @Paul We are not editing the file, just printing output. If you get the desired result, you can do: `awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/^[A-Za-z]+=[0-9]+$/) sub("^.*=", "", $i)}{print}' file.txt >output.txt` to save it in the file `output.txt` or if you have GNU `awk`: `awk -i inplace '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i~/^[A-Za-z]+=[0-9]+$/) sub("^.*=", "", $i)}{print}' file.txt`

Comment: sorry wrong translate. I meant still have output with no changes. When i delete IF statement it looks your script works -  awk -v OFS="\t" '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) sub("^.*=", "", $i)}{print}' infile. I think it could be use like this no?

Comment: @Paul Yes, as far as your example is concerned that should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{gsub(/[A-Z]=/,"")}1' file

5 8 . 8
4 . . 4
8 . . 3
```

Comment: Very nice to use gsub function... Thank you for reply!